# I want to create a c++ program that will generate a random string of user specified lenght (i.e min and max) at runtime

Tags: c++

The objective is to create it using user defined functions. such a C++ program which have a user defined function (Name: GenerateRandomWords) whose functionality is to generate random words using english alphabets e.g. Differerent website offer random generated password to use. Save All these words in text File (Name: Output.txt) as well as in an array of type string. The problem I am facing being an amaetuer is that it successfully generates 1st word and stores it in the string but when The loop starts for the second word to be generated the program runs for a while and then ends. this is the code , thanks in advance for the help:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

static const char alphanum[] =
"0123456789"
"!@#$%^&*"
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum)-1;

char genRandom()
{

    return alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
}

int main()
{
    int n = 0, a = 0;
    cout << "Howe many strings you want to generate\t";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Lenght of each :\t";
    cin >> a;
    string le;
    string ar[] = { "" };
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < a; j++)
        {

            le += genRandom();
        }
        ar[i] = le;
        le = "";
        cout << ar[i] << endl;

    }
    cout << "Out of both loop\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << ar[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: `ar` is only of size 1. So you have UB when indexing positions after that. Just use a `vector<string>` instead.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at [Pseudo-random number generation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) & [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
string ar[] = { "" };
```

you are creating an array of strings of size 1. So when you try to add the second string into this array, you invoke undefined behaviour. If you just use a `vector<string>` you won't have this problem:

```
vector<string> ar;
```

and on the line you are doing:

```
ar[i] = le;
```

you should do:

```
ar.push_back(le);
```

Here's a working [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9UYP-o).

Also, your "random" choices are not very random. Check out the [`random`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header for how you can do this better.

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement, you wants to get the length of each string and the number of strings to be printed using a specified character arrayed variable `alphanum` and create `output.txt` to save it.

Consider at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>

const char alphanum[] =
    "0123456789"
    "!@#$%^&*"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

void generate(int, int);
void setOutput(char[]);

main(void)
{
    int length, strings;

    std::cout << "How many strings & length (sep. by SPACE): ";
    std::cin >> strings >> length;

    srand(time(0));
    generate(length, strings);

    return 0;
}

void generate(int len, int str)
{
    char array[len];
    int max = sizeof(alphanum) / sizeof(alphanum[0]);
    std::ofstream output("output.txt");

    for (int k = 1; k <= str; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
            array[i] = alphanum[(rand() % max) + 1];

        std::cout << array << std::endl;
        output << array << std::endl;
    }
}
```

> **Output**

```
How many strings & length (sep. by SPACE): 5 5
5Xe*%%
xOD8TQ
YfrM*X
#j&L5&
U8*EYB
```

> **Note:** Firslty, remember the `srand()` will let the random values change each time you execute the program. Secondly, this program will generate an `output.txt` to meet your criteria.

Enjoy!